# Flipping 10 coins, what's the probability to get at least 4 tails and at least 4 heads?

Tags: probability

Say I am flipping 10 unfair coins where the probability for tails is 0.51 and for heads is 0.49 and I want to know what's the probability to get **at least 4 identical results**.

What I was trying to do is as follows:

- Event $A$ is **at least 4 flips are tails**.
- Event $B$ is **at least 4 flips are heads**.

then I tried the following

$$ \Pr(\text{at least 4 identical results}) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A\cap B) $$

$\Pr(A) = \sum_{k=4}^{10}{{10}\choose{k}} 0.51^k 0.49^{10-k} = 0.8440393217987$

$\Pr(B) = \sum_{k=4}^{10}{{10}\choose{k}} 0.49^k 0.51^{10-k} = 0.8112268280963$

$\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(\text{exactly 4 tails}) + \Pr(\text{exactly 5 tails}) + \Pr(\text{exactly 6 tails}) = 0.655266149895$

The problem is that I get $\Pr(\text{at least 4 identical results}) = 1$.

Can you please help me figure out the mistake?

Comment: The probability of at least 4 identical results is different from the probability of at least 4 tails **and** at least 4 heads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that you have at least 4 identical results (at least 4 tails **or** at least 4 heads) is 1 by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). After 3 heads and 3 tails, there isn't any other value the coin can take. So you'll *always* have at least 4 identical results. That's why your rather complicated sum ends up with a very simple answer.

If you want instead at least 4 tails **and** at least 4 heads, you just need the sum $$\Pr(\text{exactly 4 tails}) + \Pr(\text{exactly 5 tails}) + \Pr(\text{exactly 6 tails}) = 0.655266149895$$

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible that both $A$ and $B$ do not occur. $A\cup B$ covers all possibilities.

$$P(A\cup B)=1$$